# How can I read a very long BLOB column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, express, oracle11g, blob

I want to connect a Node Express API with an Oracle 11g Database which has a table with a BLOB column. I want to read it using a SQL query, but the problem is that the BLOB column can have a very long text, more than 100k characters. How can i do this?

I tried using: `select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(COLUMN_NAME)) from TABLE_NAME`.
But it returns 'raw variable length too long'.

I can make multiple queries in a loop and then join them if it was necessary, but I haven't found how bring just a part of the blob.

Comment: Oracle has built-in operations to stream it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [node-oracledb module](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/) to access Oracle Database (which you are probably already doing, but don't mention).

By default, node-oracledb will return LOBs as Lob instances that you can stream from.  Alternatively you can fetch the data directly as a String or Buffer, which is useful for 'small' LOBs.  For 100K, I would just get the data as a Buffer, which you can do by setting:

```
oracledb.fetchAsBuffer = [ oracledb.BLOB ];
```

Review the [Working with CLOB, NCLOB and BLOB Data](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#lobhandling) documentation, and examples like [blobhttp.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/blobhttp.js) and the other `lob*.js` files in the [examples directory](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).

You may also want to look at https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/ which shows Express and node-oracledb.